# Web context not registered in domain mode - JBoss/WildFly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I have a war file with a bunch of EJBs and static HTML pages. When running the server in domain/cluster mode, I cannot access the HTML files. EJBs work fine.

In the server log, there is no message that undertow is registering the web context. But, the subsystem is described in domain.xml, and there are no error messages.

`http://localhost:8080` shows the WildFly welcome page, buy if I try to access my own page (`http://localhost:8080/mycontext/index.html`), I get 404.

Everything works fine in standalone mode. The server is started using the full-ha profile, and full-ha-sockets. There is only one, master node. I tried JBoss AS 7, WildFly 8 and 9 :)

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Got the solution in [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/message/884377)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have FileSystem deployment in clustering mode.
So you have to deploy your war using the CLI or the web console.

Comment: The application is deployed using CLI.